# Integral of delta function evaluated with a sine function inside

Tags: probability, calculus

> I am trying to evaluate the integral
> $$
> f(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\tfrac{2}{\pi}\delta\mathopen{}\left(x-\tfrac{v_i^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}\right)\mathclose{}.
> $$
> This represents the probability of a projectile hitting a certain target 100 meters away with a given initial speed $v_i$.

I have to perform a change of variable to apply one of the properties of the delta function, but the problem is the sine function. My teacher hinted I have to integrate from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and then from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$, but I don't understand why or how.

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Related : [Physical meaning of the Jacobian in relation to Dirac delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371700/physical-meaning-of-the-jacobian-in-relation-to-dirac-delta-function/371706#371706).

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 2):

> I have to integrate from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and then from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$.

Integrals with Dirac deltas are much easier to solve if the integration variable is present directly inside the delta, instead of encased in an underlying function: that is, $\int \delta(u-u_0)F(u)\mathrm du$ is easier to evaluate than $\int \delta(f(u)-u_0)F(u)\mathrm du$. (Having said this, the latter form [is perfectly standard if you know the rules for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function).)

For that reason, your integral is easier to handle if you transform the integration variable from $\theta$ to $\xi=\frac{v_i^2}{g}\sin(2\theta)$. However, for this change of variables to work when there is a Dirac delta in the integrand, you need to make sure that the transformation function is monotonic. In your case, when $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$, the new variable $\xi$ goes from $0$ to $v_i^2/g$ and back to $0$, which means that if you applied the transformation rules directly without thinking about it, you would get
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mathrm d\theta 
\longrightarrow
\int_0^0 \mathrm d\xi
$$
which would give zero identically. However, if you split it into the "going up" and "going down" segments separately, you get
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\mathrm d\theta 
\longrightarrow
\int_0^{v_i^2/g} \mathrm d\xi
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\mathrm d\theta 
\longrightarrow
\int_{v_i^2/g}^0 \mathrm d\xi,
$$
and each of them has a separate chance of intersecting with the Dirac delta.

Comment: Thank you, I just I have one more question. The limits of integration change like you wrote because the function is inside of the delta function?

Comment: The changes in the limits of integration are standard. If you change from $x$ to $y=f(x)$, then the integration transforms as $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \mathrm dx \longrightarrow \int_{f(x_1)}^{f(x_2)} \frac{\mathrm dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}.$$

Comment: Yes, I figure it out, I did the whole problem and makes senses. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: I thought I understand but I dont understand the final result, after you break the integral into two, you can apply the substituion, but how you get the final result, so if I replace the expression depending on theta by u and change limits of integration, I have a delta function centered on x with limits of integration from 0 to vi^2/g . But I dont know what conclusion to draw because the density function is 2/pi and it is a constant.

Comment: @AnaBranco Comment threads are not the place for this kind of back-and-forth; take it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) instead.

Comment: done, i took it to the chat. i didnt know about it.